# Dataframe add new rows from existing ones

Tags: r, dplyr

My current data:

```
Type             Country        Score
University       Australia       10
University       Brazil          10
University       Hong Kong       10
College          Australia       10
College          Brazil          10
College          Hong Kong       10
```

Now, I want to have a summary of new rows created from the above data as shown below. The new rows are a sum of the scores for each university and college in a country.

```
Type             Country         Score
University       Australia       10
University       Brazil          10
University       Hong Kong       10
College          Australia       10
College          Brazil          10
College          Hong Kong       10
All              Australia       20
All              Brazil          20
All              Honk Kong       20
```

I know I can write a loop to iterate over the data and check the countries but maybe I can use packages like `dplyr` to achieve what I want.

Comment: Based on the description, may be you need `df1 %>% group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% summarise(col3 = sum(col3)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(Col1 = 'All') %>% bind_rows(df1, .)`

Comment: Hi, please see the edit. The original question was not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to `group_by` 'Country' get the `sum` of 'Score', create a new column 'Type' with "All" and bind the rows with original data

```
library(dplyr)
df1  %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(Score = sum(Score)) %>%
  mutate(Type = "All") %>% 
  bind_rows(df1, .)
#        Type   Country Score
#1 University Australia    10
#2 University    Brazil    10
#3 University Hong Kong    10
#4    College Australia    10
#5    College    Brazil    10
#6    College Hong Kong    10
#7        All Australia    20
#8        All    Brazil    20
#9        All Hong Kong    20
```

Comment: your solution works, but did you have any warning like "binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector"

Comment: @fanbondi the warning is just to remind you that `bind_rows()` will convert the combined variable to character automatically when binding factor and character ones. It doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Or in base R you can do it with `aggregate`

```
Extra = cbind("All", aggregate(df$Score, list(df$Country), sum))
names(Extra) = names(df)
rbind(df, Extra)
        Type   Country Score
1 University Australia    10
2 University    Brazil    10
3 University Hong Kong    10
4    College Australia    10
5    College    Brazil    10
6    College Hong Kong    10
7        All Australia    20
8        All    Brazil    20
9        All Hong Kong    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method with `ave()`:

```
df2 <- within(df1, {Type <- "All" ; Score <- ave(Score, Country, FUN = sum)})
rbind(df1, unique(df2))

#         Type   Country Score
# 1 University Australia    10
# 2 University    Brazil    10
# 3 University Hong Kong    10
# 4    College Australia    10
# 5    College    Brazil    10
# 6    College Hong Kong    10
# 7        All Australia    20
# 8        All    Brazil    20
# 9        All Hong Kong    20
```